# How can I split the data contained in a field into multiple lines?

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on an SSRS report. One of the fields usually contains data that is in the form of an array:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuZhP.png)

When the report runs, the business wants each item contained in the array on its on line. Something like this:

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmc33.png)

How can I achieve this when I will not know how many items the array could contain? It could only be 1 item, or 20? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

I thought about using the Split function using calculated fields, but without knowing how many items might be in the array for a given record, I am stumped.

Comment: what is your backend? are you using SQL Server or something like that? If so.. look at doing this as part of your dataset instead of the front end

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wanted to show each entry in FieldC on a new line then you could do this quite easily using SPLIT() and JOIN().

```
=JOIN(SPLIT(Fields!FieldC.Value, "; "), vbcrlf)
```

However, if you actually want to 'generate' a row for each entry in FieldC then you will probably have to do this in your dataset query. It's pretty simple though.

Here's some sample data  to start with

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (FieldA varchar(10), FieldB varchar(10), FieldC varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
    ('Data1', 'Data2', 'Car; Truck; Van'),
    ('Data3', 'Data4', 'Red; Green; Blue; Yellow')

SELECT 
    * 
    FROM @t t 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) as splitCol FROM string_split(FieldC, ';')) x
```

The actual query to return the data just gets each row as normal then then uses CROSS APPLY to generate a row for each `value` returned from the `string_split` when we pass FieldC to it. I've then trimmed the value to get rid of an extra spaces etc.

This query returns the following which can then be easily used in your reports.

[image]